# Python script job not running on Azure Batch - ODBC error

Tags: python, azure, odbc, azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch

I am trying to run a Python job using a VM on Azure Batch. It's a simple script to add a line to my Azure SQL Database. I downloaded the ODBC connection string straight from my Azure portal yet I get this error. The strange thing is I can run the script perfectly fine on my own machine. I've configured the VM to install the version of Python that I need and then execute my script - I'm at a complete loss. Any ideas?

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:svr-something.database.windows.net,fakeport232;Database=db-something-prod;Uid=something@svr-something;Pwd{fake_passwd};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "D:\batch\tasks\apppackages\batch_python_test1.02018-11-12-14- 
>         30\batch_python_test\python_test.py", line 12, in 
>           r'Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:svr- 
>         mydatabase.database.windows.net,'
>         pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
>         Data 
>         source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Answer (score 0):

Being new to Azure Batch I didn't realise the virtual machines didn't come with ODBC drivers installed. I wrote a .bat file to install drivers on the node when the pool is allocated. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the ODBC driver in each compute nodes of the pool.

Put the below commands inside a shell script file startup_tasks.sh:

```
sudo apt-get -y update;
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive;
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip;
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils apt-transport-https;
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - ;
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list ;
sudo apt-get -y update ;
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 ;
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y install mssql-tools ;
echo 'export PATH=\"$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin\"' >> ~/.bash_profile ;
echo 'export PATH=\"$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin\"' >> ~/.bashrc ;
source ~/.bashrc && sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev ;
```

Give bin/bash -c "startup_tasks.sh" as a startup task in azure batch pool.This will install the ODBC driver 17 in each nodes.

And then in your connection string change the ODBC driver version to 17